# Template class if statement scope

Tags: c++, templates

My program is meant to execute a few simple tasks on a stack which has a data type controlled dby the user. I have a function outside of main which is being called inside main:

```
void interface (&Stack)
```

which needs to accept many different implementations of

```
 template <class T> Stack
```

For example, it needs to accept stacks of ints, doubles, etc. The rest of my implementation is error free. But if i use

```
void interface (&Stack)
```

The compiler says I need template arguments. But if i specify one (eg. int) then I'd be ignoring the other data types my program needs to use for the Stack class!

If i use

```
void interface (&Stack<T>)
```

The compiler says that the argument is invalid.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a template parameter first:

```
template<typename T>
void interface(Stack<T>);
```